# How to combine multiple build plugins into a single import?

Tags: maven, maven-3

For different projects, I am often using the same build plugins such as:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.3.RELEASE</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>repackage</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>add-source</id>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>add-source</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <sources>
                            <source>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/java</source>
                        </sources>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        ...
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Is it possible to combine these into a single maven plugin so that all I would need is something like:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>my.awesome.group</groupId>
            <artifactId>my-awesome-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.RELEASE</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: First I would ask why you need the build-helper-maven-plugin in a spring-boot context ?

Comment: @khmarbaise I have a library that generates models and I try to avoid committing code that is generated, so I have it generate the code to the directory `${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/java`

That build-helper-maven-plugin adds a source root to the target/generated-sources directory that is ignored in git

Comment: If you have the library than I would suggest to create a plugin which handles that in a convenient way...and no there is no way to combine multiple plugins into a single one (ok you could really do hack it but I strongly discourage you to do that)...BTW: What kind of library does code generation ? Self implemented ?

Comment: @khmarbaise Thanks for the information!  An example of a library that does model generation is https://github.com/web3j/web3j-maven-plugin.  It takes solidity source files and generates java beans to interact with smart contracts on Ethereum.

Comment: I've taken a look into web3j-maven-plugin which does not handle the adding of the source correctly to the compiler paths which should be done always by a maven plugin which generates any kind of source code. Furthermore the convention it defines are simply wrong cause a plugin should never generate into `src/..` at all..The destination for generation is `target/generated-sources/*`... So I would file in ticket which should require the default behaviour of a maven plugin...otherwise it violates the convention over configuration paradigm.